# pubSubToBq getAttribute from message

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I want to extract attributes from pubsub message and use it as a part of destination table name for BQ.
Here is I process each pubsub message:

```html
  static class PubsubMessageToFailsafeElementFn
      extends DoFn<PubsubMessage, FailsafeElement<PubsubMessage, String>> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
      PubsubMessage message = context.element();
      assert message != null;
      context.output(
          FailsafeElement.of(message, new String(message.getPayload(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    }
  }
```

Here is I convert all messages to TableRow to insert in BQ:

```html
  static class PubsubMessageToTableRow
      extends PTransform<PCollection<PubsubMessage>, PCollectionTuple> {

    private final Options options;

    PubsubMessageToTableRow(Options options) {
      this.options = options;
    }

    @Override
    public PCollectionTuple expand(PCollection<PubsubMessage> input) {

      PCollectionTuple jsonToTableRowOut =
          input
              // Map the incoming messages into FailsafeElements so we can recover from failures
              // across multiple transforms.

              .apply("MapToRecord", ParDo.of(new PubsubMessageToFailsafeElementFn()))
              .apply(
                      "JsonToTableRow",
                      FailsafeJsonToTableRow.<PubsubMessage>newBuilder()
                              .setSuccessTag(TRANSFORM_OUT)
                              .setFailureTag(TRANSFORM_DEADLETTER_OUT)
                              .build());

      // Re-wrap the PCollections so we can return a single PCollectionTuple
      return PCollectionTuple.of(TRANSFORM_OUT, jsonToTableRowOut.get(TRANSFORM_OUT))
              .and(TRANSFORM_DEADLETTER_OUT, jsonToTableRowOut.get(TRANSFORM_DEADLETTER_OUT));
```

And the last process, I upload all the TableRow to BQ:

```html
    PCollectionTuple convertedTableRows =
        messages
            /*
             * Step #2: Transform the PubsubMessages into TableRows
             */
            .apply("ConvertMessageToTableRow", new PubsubMessageToTableRow(options));

    WriteResult writeResult =
        convertedTableRows.get(TRANSFORM_OUT)
            .apply(
                "WriteSuccessfulRecords",
                BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                    .withoutValidation()
                    .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                    .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                    .withExtendedErrorInfo()
                    .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
                    .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.retryTransientErrors())
                    .to(**SHOULD BE MESSAGE ATTRIBUTE HERE**));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [DynamicDestinations](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/DynamicDestinations.html) in the BigQueryIO `to` field.